# MYVLOOKUP for finding multiple values of partial matches and fitting them in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, match, partial

I am currently trying to use the following VBA code to find and extract information from multiple cells into one cell. It works perfectly fine for exact matches, but I would like it to also find partial matches. I know I must add As variant into the Syntax, but am unsure how to execute it.

Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

    'Update 20150310
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng = pValue Then
            xResult = xResult & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
    Next
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult

End Function
```

I expect the output to be listed on top of another in a single cell for all partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Like` instead of `=`

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

    'Update 20150310
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng Like "*" & pValue & "*" Then 'using Like and  "*" "*" means anything containing pValue
            xResult = xResult & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
    Next
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult

End Function
```

You must watch for this:

1. `Like` is `Case Sensitive`
2. `"*" & Variable` looks for any string which end is your variable
3. `Variable & "*"` looks for any string which start is your variabel